# Set multiple session variables

Tags: java, spring, session, junit, controller

I have written test cases for spring controller. I have set multiple session attributes in httpservletrequest.

```
WebApplicationContext wac;
MockHttpSession session= new MockHttpSession(wac.getServletContext)
MockHttpServletRequest request= new MockHttpServletRequest (wac.getServletContext)
```

I am setting single session variable as

```
session.setAttribute("uname","jones");
request.setSession(session);
```

But How I can add multiple session objects like password,age,etc.like

```
session.setAttribute("pwd","zzzzzz");
session.setAttribute("age","44");
```

When I do this it is overwriting the previous session object.

Comment: what do you mean by overwriting?? It means "uname" is overwritten by age that is you are able to access only one attribute age or whole object values get overridden

Comment: yes. And getting null.

Comment: @BelieveToLive Prashant is asking you whether one of two options is the case. You can't answer "yes" to an "(a) or (b)" question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create multiple session variables like this:

```
// Create a session object if it is already not  created.
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
// set session attributes
  session.setAttribute("uname","jones");
  session.setAttribute("pwd","zzzzzz");
  session.setAttribute("age","44");
```